# Orchard CMS: Creating ContentItems in a loop builds up a delay

Tags: c#, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

**The root problem**
The problem I am facing stems from the need to import data from spreadsheets.
Once an import has been started the user must be able to leave the page and return at a later point when the import is done.
So far the options I am aware of are the scheduled tasks and the background workers in Orchard who as I understand it are both triggered once a minute by the sweep. (Please let me know if there is a better option I have overlooked)

**The issue**
I basically have to create new content items in a loop. And after encountering some issues for some time I have set up a very simple test with an ajax call creating X dummy items for each call and timing it.
I find that the time it takes to create an item increases slightly for each iteration. Where the first item may take 20 ms to create, nr 200 in the loop would take 150 ms to create. And there seems to be no roof to this, it just keep getting worse for each iteration.

In case you want to see the test code:

```
    public TimeSpan CreateRandomItem(int nr)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        ContentItem item = _services.ContentManager.New("MyItemType");
        var myPart = item.As<MyPart>();
        myPart.Name = "Test nr " + nr;
        _services.ContentManager.Create(item);

        sw.Stop();
        return sw.Elapsed;
    }

    public JsonResult TestCreation(int amount, int nrReached)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = nrReached + 1; i <= (nrReached + amount); i++)
        {
            TimeSpan elapsed = _associationImportService.CreateRandomAssociation(i);
            sb.Append("\n - Nr " + i + " took " + elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + "ms");
        }
        return Json(sb.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Once the loop is complete the ajax call triggers again and now the delay is drastically reduced, starting over around 30 ms. It does not completely recover in the slight interval between the first and second ajax call, but it does make a huge difference.

I assume this may be related to leaving the WorkContext maybe?
But I can not find a way to force this to happen while I remain inside the loop.
Since the sweep only runs once a minute I can't think of a way to avoid this loop.

**The question**
Is there anything I can do to avoid this delay buildup while inside the loop, or possibly another approach to running the import that I have overlooked?
(Keep in mind this must run in the background while the user is not on the page)
(It may be worth mentioning the item I last tested with does not have a search index from Lucene, but it does have fields which I assume need to be added to the field indexing. If that makes a difference)

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182272%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Fair point. A performance test shouldn't contain that mistake. I updated the code to use StringBuilder and ran it again with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've faced a similar issue with creating lots of content items during a data import

The steps we have taken are:

- Move the import to an [Orchard Command](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Using-the-command-line-interface)

  - This means that you are outside of the IIS worker process and any timeouts / locks related to running your creation code there
  - This might not be an option for you if you need to keep your process in the Orchard UI.
- Move the work to batches instead and after each item, or every x items inside your loop call

  - `_orchardServices.TransactionManager.RequireNew()` to force the transaction to be committed
  - `_orchardServices.ContentManager.Clear()` to clear out references to any content items

You'll need to inject an `IOrchardServices` to access these methods.

Comment: As you mentioned I need to keep the import in the UI. But I followed your second suggestion and it works like a charm. There's an overhead to calling RequireNew and Clear so I only call them every X iterations and the delay resets. Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver, I will build a shrine in your honor!

Comment: Wow, this made a huge difference. Thanks!